# How can I make a twitter like homepage with django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

I am right now new to the Django web framework. I want to make a twitter-like/facebook-like homepage where a user can post a status or update and also view other ures' posts but I can't do that because when a user is logged in, he posts an update but can't view it is his home. He can view all the posts when he logs out. Here is my views function for this.

> views.py

```
def index(request):
   posts = NewPost.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")

   if request.user.is_authenticated:
      if request.method == "POST":
          post = NewPostForm(request.POST)
          user = request.user
          timestamp = datetime.now()
          if post.is_valid:
              post = post.save(commit=False)
              postdata = NewPost(post=post,user=user,timestamp=timestamp)
              postdata.save()

          return render(request,"network/index.html",{
              "post" : post,
              "user" : user,
              "timestamp" : timestamp
          })

      else:
          post = NewPostForm()
          return render(request,"network/index.html",{
              "post" : post
          })

  return render(request,"network/index.html",{
      "posts" : posts
  })
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.index, name="index"),
   path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
   path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
   path("register", views.register, name="register"),    
]
```

> templates

```html
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <h1>All Posts</h1>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="border border-success" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                <div style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    <h3>New Post</h3>
                    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %} 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- <textarea name="post" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="What is in your mind? "></textarea> -->
                            {{ post.as_table }}
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="Submit" value="Post">
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div id="posts" class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% for posts in posts %}
                    <ul>
                         <li class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ posts.user }}</h5> 
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">{{ posts.timestamp }}</h6>
                                <h3 class="card-text">{{ posts.post }}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                {% empty %}
                    <h6>No post availabel </h6>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

If a user tries to post an update, he clicks the post button but the form gets disappear. [my problem](https://youtu.be/EJjntQPgYco)

Answer (score 0):

- You have to pass the `user` in the context in `else` block to make the form appear (if user is_authenticated then only you are displaying the form).
- You have to pass the all posts to the context to make all posts visible.

Here is what you have to do.

```
def index(request):
   posts = NewPost.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")

   if request.user.is_authenticated:
      user = request.user # changed here
      if request.method == "POST":
          post = NewPostForm(request.POST)
          timestamp = datetime.now()
          if post.is_valid:
              post = post.save(commit=False)
              postdata = NewPost(post=post,user=user,timestamp=timestamp)
              postdata.save()

          return render(request,"network/index.html",{
              "post" : post,
              "posts" : posts,
              "user" : user,
              "timestamp" : timestamp
          })

      else:
          post = NewPostForm()
          return render(request,"network/index.html",{
              "post" : post,
              "posts" : posts,
              "user" : user, # added here
              "timestamp" : timestamp # added now, remove if not needed
          })

   return render(request,"network/index.html",{
      "posts" : posts
   })
```